# How does iOS 10.3.3 know when a scammer calls?

Tags: ios, iphone

It shows SCAM LIKELY as the caller id. It didn't used to do that. Does it send all incoming call numbers to Apple for them to analyze?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.payetteforward.com/iphone-scam-likely-why/ has a good explanation.

"Why Does My iPhone Say “Scam Likely”?

Your iPhone says “Scam Likely” because your wireless carrier introduced a new feature called Scam ID or Scam Lock that automatically changes the caller ID from the phone number to “Scam Likely” if the number calling is a known or suspected scammer."

Answer (score 3):

Just to supplement John's answer, it appears [T-Mobile deployed it out for its subscribers and MetroPCS](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2017/03/t-mobile-scam-block-scam-id.html) (which I see in your screen shot). There's a neat fact sheet that also shows some operations [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwit-v-I66nVAhUnrVQKHZ2LA3AQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnewsroom.t-mobile.com%2Fdoc_download.cfm%3Fdoc_id%3D226&usg=AFQjCNF36jKN30gBGBBAryN1PFkZmSPiLQ)

> How to Get Scam ID and Scam Block
>   T-Mobile will enable Scam ID for all T-Mobile customers on a rolling basis beginning with T-Mobile ONE customers on April 5
>   New T-Mobile ONE customers will automatically get Scam ID beginning April 5
>   T-Mobile postpaid customers can also enable Scam ID for themselves beginning April 5 by dialing #ONI# (#664#) and
>   pressing the call button in their phone’s dialer
>   To turn on Scam Block, dial #ONB# (#662#)
>   To turn off Scam Block, dial #OFB# (#632#)
>   To check whether Scam Block is on or off, dial #STS# (#787#)